# How to put a tableView's Edit button in the toolbar when a search bar is shown (as in Apple's mail app)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

I would like to put the **Edit** button in the **toolbar** at the bottom. The Edit button is usually instantiated with `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem` in `viewDidLoad` and normally placed in the navigation bar.

When trying to put the Edit button (= `self.editButtonItem`) in the toolbar (by adding it to the toolbar items), the buttom does not appear. However, all other toolbar items, which I have added using Interface Builder are presented correctly.

How would you recommend adding this button to the toolbar?

The reason for adding the Edit button to the toolbar is to be enable the table's edit mode when a `UISearchBar` enabled search is currently active and the searchbar hides the edit button in the navigation bar.

I would like to get the same behavior as in Apple's email app, where the Edit button is shown in the toolbar when search is active.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Edit button to the toolbar this way:

```
self.editButton = 
[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit 
                                             target:nil 
                                             action:nil] 
autorelease];

NSArray *toolbarItems = 
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.editButton,nil];

self.toolbar.items = toolbarItems;
```

If you want to hide/show it, just toggle its `hidden` property:

```
self.editButton.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: I have added the Edit button using your code snipped to `-searchDisplayController:didShowSearchResultsTableView:` and the button is shown in the toolbar when the search bar is displayed. However, nothing happens when I tap on the Edit button (in contrast to the 'real' Edit button [`editButtonItem`], which changes from 'Edit' to 'Done' and toggles the table's edit mode by firing `setEditing`). What would be the best way to have the toolbar's Edit button perform the same way? Thank you!

Comment: Well, you gotta implement that yourself. For the button, you can just substitute the button with the "Done" one. Use `UIBarButtonSystemItemDone` instead of `UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit`. To put the table view in editing mode, just create a method where you do that and tell the button to call it when pressed. You can do it like this: `[self.editButton setTarget:self];` `[self.editButton setAction:@selector(yourMethod)];`. Got it?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it manually, by creating a new [`UIBarButtonItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with style `UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit`. Then simply add it to the tabbar, assign a target and action and call `[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];`.

Comment: I have assigned target and action and tried to set the table in edit mode in my 'action' code: `- (IBAction)editToolbar:(id)sender {
    [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    self.editToolbarButton.title = @"Done";
}` However, the table remains in non-Edit mode as long as the search bar is shown. As soon as the search bar is dismissed, the table enter the edit mode. However, I need to the table to enter the mode with the search bar and search results shown (as in the mail app). Any thoughts on that?